# How to find a probability density function.

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Suppose $X$ and $Y$ are random variables that are independent also $X$ and $Y$ are uniformly distributed on the interval $(0, 1)$.
If $Z=\max \{ X, Y \}$. Then find the probability that $Z \leq z$ and then determine the probability density function of $Z$.

So far I have said that both $X$ and $Y$ are $1$ in the interval $(0,1)$ and $0$ elsewhere.

I then said that $P(Z \leq z)=P(x \leq z~\cap~y \leq z)$ so we can split these up and then work through to get this to be equal to.

$$ \int_{-\infty}^zdx \times \int_{-\infty}^zdy=z^2$$ but then I got really confused at to what $z$ even wasand how to proceed with the question. Also the $z^2$ can't be right as this gives values greater than $1$.

Any help?

Comment: If $0 \le z \le 1$ then $0 \le z^2 \le 1$

Comment: If $F(z)=z^2$ is the probability that $Z = \max \{ X, Y \} \le z$ then the density of $Z$ is $f(z)=\frac{dF}{dz}$

Answer (score 1):

I usually advice to go very careful step by step in problems like these. First check where $Z$ is supported, ie its domain, in this case $D_Z=[0,1]$. Next we look at the CDF. Choose $z\in D_Z$, then (like you did) $F_Z(z) = P(X\le z)P(Y\le z) = z\cdot z = z^2$. Next we define its pdf by differentiating to get $f(z) = 2z$ for $0\le z\le 1$ and $f(z) = 0$ otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

The double integral is, because the support of the two distributions is over $(0;1)$:

$$\int_0^{z}\operatorname d x\times\int_0^{z} \operatorname d y\qquad \mbox{if }z\in (0;1) \text{ and } 0 \text{ if }z\leq 0\text{ and }0\text{ if }z\geq 1$$

Thus the CDF of Z is: $F_Z(z)=z^2 \; \mathbf 1_{0<z<1} + \mathbf 1_{z\geq 1}$

Hence the PDF of Z is the derivative: $f_Z(z) = 2 z  \; \mathbf 1_{0<z<1} $

Or expressed as a piecewise function:

$$f_Z(z) = \begin{cases}2 z & : 0<z<1 \\ 0 & :\text{elsewhere}\end{cases}$$

Comment: Actually, the value is $1$ if $z \geq 1$ since the upper limit really should be written as $\min\{z, 1\}$.

Comment: Noted. @DilipSarwate